# Remove duplicates in Tableau

Tags: database, duplicates, tableau-api

I am trying to remove duplicates from the ID field, I would like it so that only the earliest retention academic period is associated with the unique ID. For example:

```
Status | ID | Profile Period | Retention Period | Academic Period 

Retained | 654321 | 200610 | 200620 | 200620

Retained | 654321 | 200610 | 200710 | 200710

Retained | 654321 | 200610 | 200720 | 200720

CODO IN | 123456 | 200510 | 200520 | 200520

CODO IN | 123456 | 200510 | 200610 | 200610

CODO IN | 123456 | 200510 | 200620 | 200620
```

So what I want is to keep the repeated terms for Retained IDs, however, I want to the repeated CODO In values to take the earliest retention period:

```
Retained | 654321 | 200610 | 200620 | 200620

Retained | 654321 | 200610 | 200710 | 200710

Retained | 654321 | 200610 | 200720 | 200720

CODO IN | 234567 | 200510 | 200520 | 200520
```

I have tried {Fixed [ID]: MIN [Retention Period]} but it doesn't seem to remove all the repeats for CODO In (i.e. I still see the counts for 200610 and 200620).

Any suggestions on how to approach this task?

Comment: Please use the formatting tools in the future. I only partially fixed it. I could give you an answer to this but it would have to be in R (which technically you can use in Tableau but it's truly a real pain - you've got to set up a server in R and interact with Tableau in a very clunky and limited way). Better to wait for a Tableau expert to help you I think.

Comment: I don't use Tableau but I assume you get this data from a SQL query. If you post the actual database you're running this on then someone might post a SQL based answer. This kind of thing is typically achieved with anlytical / partition database functions but not all database versions support them

Answer (score 0):

As other commenters have mentioned this work is usually best dealt with before the data is inputted into Tableau. This is because if this data is not required to be visualised it is best practise to remove it to keep the dashboard performant and simple.

However, if you require a solution in Tableau you were on the right track with a LOD. If you nest it with an IF statement so that only the CODO Status duplicates are remove you should get your desired result.

So create the following as a calculated field:

```
iif([Status]='CODO IN', 
[Retention Period] = {Fixed [ID]: MIN([Retention Period])}
, TRUE)
```

Then if you drag this calculated field to the filters shelf and select 'TRUE' you will then remove the duplicates.

Let me know how it goes.